# I have created automation Script for Login process, So Can I Re-Call the @Test method when it gives the Validation error message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, login-automation

I have below fields:

1. Email
2. Password
3. Submit button
4. Validation Error message

I have normally using XPath created the Script, but I want to Re-call when Wrong Credential is Entered.

```
        public static void main (String args [])

        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Aazad\\Selenium\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
            SignUPDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            SignUPDriver.manage().window().maximize();

            SignUPDriver.get(URL);

            SignUPDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            @Test
            public void Login() 
            {
            LoginDriver.get(URL);
            LoginDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            LoginDriver.findElement(By.xpath("Login Page')]").click();
            System.out.println("Please Enter your EmailID: ");
            LoginDriver.findElement(By.xpath("Email").sendKeys(FName1); 
            LoginDriver.findElement(By.xpath("Password").sendKeys(FName1); 
            LoginDriver.findElement(By.xpath("Submit").click();
            }
        }
```

Hi I want to recall the @Test Method when it gives the Validation message

Comment: For multiple login successfully or unsuccessfully cases you can use either array or .pdf file with selenium.

Comment: Hi @PradnyaBolli Thank you for the Editing.